# Print out the file with cancel certain character and transfer into another existing file

Tags: text-processing, awk

If my input is something like below
cat file

```
{ABC}
{ABC}
{ABC}
{ABC}
{ABC}
```

The output that I want

```
ABC
ABC
ABC
ABC
ABC
```

Is that got some ways to after generate the output and transfer the data into a existing file already ?
Example another file name is FileOne
Content is

```
123
123
123
123
123
ALphabet
```

Got any ways after use the awk command to generate the output that I wanted and transfer to the FileOne and paste after the Alphabet column?

I want something like this

```
123
123
123
123
123
Alphabet
ABC
ABC
ABC
ABC
ABC
```

Thanks if you can help me solve this.

Answer (score 0):

Easier with `sed`:

```
sed -n 's/^{\(.*\)}$/\1/p' file >> FileOne
```

With `awk`:

```
awk '/^[{].*[}]$/ {print substr($0, 2, length - 2)}' file >> FileOne
```

`>>` opens the file in *append* mode on standard output, so the output of `sed`/`awk` will be *appended* to `FileOne`.